# For which values of k the polynomial has only two real roots?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

I'm at the very beginning in algebra and also I don't speak English much. Maybe this question is very simple but I can't understand how to determine parameters in polynomials in order to find out real, rational or integer roots. Here's the polynomial:

$$x^{3} - 33x^{2} + 315x -k$$

Comment: Note:  the three (complex) roots have to add to $33$ so....

Comment: I suggest sketching a graph of $y=x^3-33x^2+315x$ and then drawing various horizontal lines representing $y=k$ to see how many times those lines cross the graph. That may help you to understand what you need to do.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515659/cubic-equations-which-have-exactly-one-real-root), for the case of exactly one real root (it must have at least one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$(x-a)(x-b)^2=x^3-(a+2b)x^2+b(b+2a)x-ab^2=x^3-33x^2+315x-k$$

Solving gives $$a+2b=33\implies a=33-2b$$$$b(b+2a)=315\implies b(b+66-4b)=315$$ so $$-3b^2+66b-315=0\implies b^2-22b+105=(b-15)(b-7)=0\implies \boxed{b=7,15}$$ Hence $a=33-2(7), 33-2(15)\implies \boxed{a=19,3}$. Thus $k=ab^2=19(7^2)=931$ or $k=ab^2=3(15^2)=675$ so $$\boxed{k=675,931}$$

Comment: Why is that the only such $k$?

Comment: How does this help the OP understand how to solve such problems on their own?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I hope the edit explains it better.

Comment: Very much so! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the equation as

$$x^3-33x^2+315x=k,$$

you need to find the possible ordinates of an horizontal line that intersects the curve in the LHS exactly twice.

If we look for the extrema,

$$3x^2-66x+315=0$$ yields the solutions $x=7,k=931$ and $x=15,k=675$ (an horizontal by an extremum intersects the curve at another point).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)$ denote the given polynomial. Since the coefficients of $P$ are real, the non-real roots of $P$ occur in conjugate pairs. Since $P$ has $3$ roots, that means that $P$ has either $1$ or $3$ real roots.

But that's counting roots with multiplicities; for example, $x(x-1)^2$ has a root of order $1$ at $x = 0$ and a root of order $2$ at $x = 1$). Polynomials have a discriminant $\Delta$ that vanishes only if it has a multiple root. (This is the same discriminant in the quadratic formula for a polynomial of degree $2$; it generalizes to higher degrees.) For a cubic polynomial $f(x) = x^3 + bx + cx + d$, it turns out to be:
\begin{align*}
\Delta &= b^2 c^2 - 4c^3 - 4b^3 d -27a^2 d^2 + 18bcd.
\end{align*}
For our polynomial $P$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Delta_P &= -27k^2 + 43362 k  - 16967475,
\end{align*}
which happens to vanish for $k = 675$ and $k = 931$. You can verify that there are exactly two distinct real roots in both those cases (we would still have $\Delta = 0$ if there were only one distinct real root): 
\begin{align*}
x^3 - 33x^2 + 315x - 675 &= (x - 3)(x-15)^2 \\
x^3 - 33x^2 + 315x - 931 &= (x - 7)(x-19)^2 &
\end{align*}
Not particularly enlightening, but it's a straightforward computation in degree $3$.

Answer (score 0):

If a 3rd-order polynomial has 2 real roots the 3rd one must be so either. Since we generally want two distinct roots there must be one duplex such root. Then we can decompose $f(x)$ as follows:
$$f(x)=(x-a)^2(x-b)$$
By differentiating we have:
$$f^{'}(x)=3x^2-66x+315=3x^2-(a+5b)x+b(a+2b)$$
therefore we get:
$$a+5b=66$$
$$b(a+2b)=315$$
which results in:
$$a=31,b=7$$
and
$$a=-9,b=15$$
therefore 
$$k=-6727,k=-1215$$